# Updating activity feed UI in realtime (getstream.io/stream-java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, getstream-io

I am new to getstream.io and I am integrating my spring-boot application with it for my activity feed. My problem is that when I add a new activity, the newly added activity is not displaying on my feed. I have to refresh the page in order to display the newly added activity. The docs on getstream.io only covers the java code and I am having trouble finding clear examples for the frontend side.

```
Here's my server side code:

public List<? extends EnrichedActivity> getActivity(String userId) throws StreamException {
        FlatFeed feed = getstream.flatFeed("user", userId);
        return feed.getEnrichedActivities().join();
    }
```

On the getsream.io, this is how they do it on their docs(client side code):

```
let notificationFeed = client.feed('notification', '1');

function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function successCallback() {
    console.log('now listening to changes in realtime');
}

function failCallback(data) {
    alert('something went wrong, check the console logs');
    console.log(data);
}

user1.subscribe(callback).then(successCallback, failCallback);
```

reference: https://getstream.io/docs/java/#frontend_realtime

Comment: Can you add some code examples of your actual application?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @wolmi I added some code above, I hope that would help!

Comment: you can subscribe for updates on a feed and update your UI when that happens; this is something you should do client-side (ie. JS/Android/iOS) and not on your server-side code

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli that's exactly what I wanted to do but I am having a hard time following through their docs and I can't find examples with complete implementation from server-side to client-side. I am new to getstream.io and JS so this is a really big problem for me. A sample code with thorough explanation might help me on this.